# Google sheet create pdf from another sheet ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi how could this code be modified to create a PDF file from another worksheet instead of the active open worksheet.
Here's part of the code I'm using and it works but I would like to create a PDF from another worksheet ID

Thanks

```
   var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var spreadsheet = spreadsheetId ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
   var ticketnum = source.getSheetByName("Print Page").getRange('X1').getValue();
   var body = 'Attached is your copy'
   var Client = source.getSheetByName("Print Page").getRange('O5').getValue();
   var Cons = source.getSheetByName("Print Page").getRange('T4').getValue() ;
   var jobN = source.getSheetByName("Ticket PDF").getRange('G9').getValue() ;
   var mailTo = source.getSheetByName("Print Page").getRange('Z1').getValue() ;
   var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Ticket').next();
   var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
   var ssID = spreadsheetId;
   var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export"+
                                                    "?format=pdf&"+
                                                     '&portrait=true' + 
                                                     '&fzr=true' +  
                                                     '&fitw=True' + 
                                                     //'&scale=4' +
                                                     '&top_margin=0.25' + 
                                                     '&bottom_margin=0.25' + 
                                                     '&left_margin=0.25' +
                                                     '&right_margin=0.25' +
                                                     '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' +  
                                                     '&gridlines=false'+
                                                     '&sheetnames=False';



     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    });

    var pdf = response.getBlob().setName( Client + "  " + ticketnum + " @ " + jobN + "  "  + '.PDF');
    folder.createFile(pdf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

In this modification, it supposes that `another worksheet ID` in your question is the other sheet in the active Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

In order to export the specific sheet in the Spreadsheet as PDF file, you can use the query parameter of `gid` as follows.

From:

```
"?format=pdf&"+
```

To:

```
"?format=pdf&gid=" + spreadsheet.getSheetByName("###").getSheetId() + "&" +
```

- In this case, please set the sheet name you want to export as a PDF to `###`.

#### Note:

- If you want to export several sheets in the Spreadsheet as a PDF file, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60068741) might be useful.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added

- You want to export the specific Spreadsheet, which is not the active Spreadsheet, as a PDF file.

In your script, please give `spreadsheetId`. When `spreadsheetId` is not given the active Spreadsheet by `var spreadsheet = spreadsheetId ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`. And `spreadsheetId` is retrieved from the active Spreadsheet. So please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var spreadsheet = spreadsheetId ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
```

#### To:

```
var spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.

var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
```

- If you want to export the specific sheet in the Spreadsheet, please use the query parameter `gid`. And if you want to export several sheets in the Spreadsheet, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60068741) might be useful.

Comment: Hi Tanaike what I'm looking for is to be able to create a PDF that is from a different worksheet not another sheet from the same worksheet by using the id of that different worksheet thanks for the quick answer

Comment: @Yvan L Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I thought that the worksheet is the sheet in a Spreadsheet. But in your question, the worksheet might be a Spreadsheet. So you want to export the specific Spreadsheet, which is not the active Spreadsheet, as a PDF file. Is my understanding correct?